# Is there an equivalent term to "Cold Turkey" for starting something instead of quitting something?

Tags: idiom-requests

**Cold Turkey** is an idiom most commonly used when quitting something that is very difficult, like smoking or drugs all at [once instead of gradually](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30089/cold-turkey-as-expression). Can you also start something "Cold Turkey" or is there another idiom that would be better? Replace the term in the following sentence.

> The obese man began running 10 miles a day [cold turkey].

Comment: Related, not duplicate: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/295693/13804

Comment: I'm not clear how you want to use your phrase.  Could you give an example of how you use cold turkey, and then another phrase with the word you want missing?

Comment: @Dan After the nicotine patch failed, he decided to quit smoking cold turkey

Comment: I've actually used cold turkey before to refer to the precipitous start of an activity, but I suppose technically that's not its normal usage. So at least I think its meaning is understandable in your sentence.  Language is how people use it.

Comment: "Cold turkey" refers to withdrawal symptoms which does only apply when _ending_ not when _starting_.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I think you are right although I do hear the term sometimes used outside of withdrawal symptoms. It makes it difficult to find an answer and suggests my question is flawed. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Are you emphasizing the difficulty or the commitment? I suppose *whole-heartedly* is a simple adverb that might work for the latter.

Comment: @shawnt00 I want emphasize the difficulty because of the suddenness

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34460/discussion-on-question-by-drai-is-there-an-equivalent-term-to-cold-turkey-for).

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Following the model answer given in comments above *(After the nicotine patch failed, he decided to quit smoking cold turkey)*

*After putting on weight over Christmas, he **threw himself/jumped in/dived in at the deep end** and started doing 2-hour marathon training sessions every morning before breakfast.*

***Throw oneself/Jump in at the deep end*** means to ​start doing something new and ​difficult without ​help or ​preparation (http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/jump-in-at-the-deep-end)

Comment: "Jumped in with both feet" is a similar, related, but slightly different phrase too. "Threw in at the deep end" suggests starting at a difficult level, which is subtly different. "Jumping in with both feet", on the other hand, suggests an immediate start with no reference to difficulty (eg you aren't testing the water with one foot and deciding whether to jump in, you're just going straight in).

Comment: Also "dived right in"

Comment: Hi @Dan this is an excellent answer of course but, uh, my one is better in this case  :-)  It's, further, a fascinating observation that conversely one can use "jumped in" indeed **precisely as one uses 'cold turkey'** in the case of quitting drugs..

Comment: "Jump in at the deep end" is best,  i think, because it conveys the idea that the approach is *potentially dangerous*, unlike "jumping in with both feet", which, in my opinion sounds like the person in question is being enthusiastic rather than possibly a bit reckless.

Answer (score 50):

The subject took to the new activity *whole hog*.

Comment: Nice, this sounds like much more of a direct analog of "cold turkey" than many of the other answers. +1

Comment: This doesn't suggest the unpleasant sudden shock of 'cold turkey'.

Answer (score 29):

Consider,

***jump in with both feet/jump in feet first***

> *jump in with both feet* also *jump with both feet into something*
>   to become involved in something quickly and completely *When she decides to get involved, she jumps in with both feet*. [Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/jump+in+with+both+feet)
>
> *The obese man jumped feet first/with both feet into running 10 miles a day*.

***take the plunge***

> *Idiom* To enter with sudden decision upon an unfamiliar course of action, as after hesitation or deliberation. [Random House](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/take--the--plunge)
>
> *The obese man took the plunge and began running 10 miles a day*.

***take the bit between one's teeth/in one's teeth/mouth***

> To do what you have decided to do in a forceful and energetic way [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/de/worterbuch/englisch-chinesisch-traditionelle/get-the-bit-between-your-teeth)
>
> *The obese man took the bit in his teeth and began running 10 miles a day*.

***grit one's teeth***

> To decide to deal with an unpleasant or difficult situation. Etymology: based on the literal meaning of grit your teeth (to press your teeth tightly together)
>
> To deal with something in a determined way; *When a test came along, I just gritted my teeth and studied harder because I knew I had to improve my grades*. [Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/grit+teeth)
>
> *The obese man gritted his teeth and began running 10 miles a day*.

[***swallow the bitter pill***](https://books.google.fr/books?id=wklsUvTEa2sC&pg=PA43&dq=%22swallowed+the+bitter+pill%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi7m5mv4anKAhUBvBQKHRY1DLEQ6AEIWjAI#v=onepage&q=%22swallowed%20the%20bitter%20pill%22&f=false)

> bitter pill: a distressing experience or result that is hard to accept (often in the expression *a bitter pill to swallow*) [Random House](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bitter-pill)
>
> *The obese man swallowed the bitter pill and began running 10 miles a day*.

Answer (score 26):

To express the unpleasantness of "cold turkey", I would suggest "biting the bullet". To [*bite the bullet*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bite-the-bullet) means:

> to ​force yourself to do something ​unpleasant or ​difficult, or to be
>   ​brave in a ​difficult ​situation

[Cambridge Dictionaries Online]

Your example sentence:

> The obese man bit the bullet and began running 10 miles a day.

Comment: Hi, LHP. I edited your answer to include a link that can support your answer. Please take a look.

Comment: I like bite the bullet! @LHP

Comment: Doesn't this  phrase carry with it, usually, the idea that you will do the unpleasant thing once only ?  Cold turkey is not only a sudden unpleasant experience it also lasts for some time.  The 'bullet', once bitten, is no longer a problem.

Comment: @Dan I'd say yes, since it's popularly cited as coming from biting down on the (relatively) soft lead of a bullet during unanesthetised surgery, which would be a one time thing. But since you only *start* something once, it's fine to "Bite the bullet and start etc."

Comment: _He found it difficult to give up cold turkey until he wound up biting the bullet._

Comment: Sorry @LHP some good arguments against this answer.

Comment: "bite the bullet" implies there was a period of procrastination before hand. "Cold turkey" doesn't do that for me, but certainly if one "quit cold turkey" that doesn't mean there was no procrastination.

Comment: Yes _biting the bullet_ is more of the **decision-taking** process which leads to the action of taking the plunge or diving at the deep end. However, this answer is good IMO and worth highlighting as relevant.

Answer (score 14):

You could say:

> The obese man ***plunged into*** (the habit of) running ten miles a day.

This implies he did it with enthusiasm. From the [Oxford Learner’s Dictionary, ***plunge into something:***](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/plunge-in)

> **2.** to start doing something in an enthusiastic way, especially without thinking carefully about what you are doing

Comment: This is closer to what I'm getting at. Also "jumped right in" might work, but I'm hoping for something that can be used int he same way as cold turkey.

Answer (score 12):

I would personally say he went at it ***full tilt***.

From Google's web search definition:

> (at) full tilt phrase of tilt
>   1. with maximum energy or force; at top speed. synonyms:  (at) full speed, at top speed, full bore, as fast as one's legs can carry one,
>   at a gallop, helter-skelter, headlong, pell-mell, at breakneck speed,
>   with great force, with full force;

Comment: This is a good thought, but your answer would be improved by explaining *why* you suggest this term, for example, by providing a dictionary definition or examples in the wild. I encourage you take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: JSONders - I added the Google web-search definition as an external addition.

Comment: Aside from that, colloquially I often use and hear (in the Mid-Western United States) the term full tilt as JSONders intends - that not only can it mean at maximum energy, but often also implies immediacy to an action.

Answer (score 11):

My suggestion: "hit the ground running". Although in the case of taking up running, this expression could come across as a pun.

Comment: I feel like this also gives the connotation that the subject was successful with whatever they started doing, instead of just saying that they started.

Comment: +1 - That was my thought. It's as close it gets in my opinion.

Answer (score 6):

One idiom that might suit this situation is "out of the blue," as in

> Out of the blue, the obese man began running 10 miles a day.

Christine Ammer, *The American Heritage Dictionary of Idioms* (1997) lists "out of the blue," along with "out of a clear blue sky" and "out of nowhere," as idioms meaning "Without warning, suddenly," and says of the first two idioms that "These metaphoric terms allude to something dropping unexpectedly from the sky." In the runner's case, what drops unexpectedly from the sky is his decision to begin running long distances without any gradual buildup to the activity.

I suppose you could also flip the description around and say that the runner "gave up his sedentary lifestyle cold turkey"—but normally the "cold turkey" phase involves a withdrawal from some activity, not a withdrawal from inactivity.

Comment: "Out of the blue" refers to the fact that it's unexpected / random.  Don't let the "suddenly" in the dictionary definition fool you.  You could describe a decision for any person to start running, even a healthy person starting gradually, as "out of the blue".  As you say, it fits because the decision is sudden, not the activity.  It's nowhere near an analog for "cold turkey".  Someone could decide, out of the blue, to quit cold turkey.  IMO, this would be better as a comment that "out of the blue" is phrase for something different, and doesn't fit.

Comment: This is good. I was also thinking "from scratch" and "from nothing" and "out of nowhere". Although these don't really convey consistency.

Answer (score 5):

**Taking the bull by the horns**, the obese man began running 10 miles a day.

> Definition: to confront a problem head-on and deal with it openly; to
>   forcefully attack a difficult situation;

[image]

Comment: I think took the bull by the horns is about control, more than the sudden and drastic change inspired by "cold turkey".

Comment: @fredsbend - I must admit that this idiom don't fully convey the abruptness of the decision.

Answer (score 5):

All of the answers (*jumped in* and so on) are excellent,

However, I'd use the expression

## "Hot turkey".

I think that would be quite clever and nice. The meaning is absolutely obvious. You are instantly implying *the same set of emotions and considerations* as when you use the phrase "cold turkey". So, it's *just like the **guy going cold turkey in French Connection** ... we're jumping in that aggressively, harmfully, with no thought of gently-easing ourselves through a new process..."*

> "We jumped in to the project hot turkey."

Very nice!

*note* CJDennis (perhaps jokingly) suggests *Hot Turkey* in a deep field comment above; CJ gets the eternal credit for this.

## But wait ...

Here's another take. I think it would be very sensible to use the phrase

## "Cold turkey."

Here's the thing: the original use of "cold turkey" was by no means in relation to ending or quitting something. It appears to be used to mean aggressively-direct **in any usage**.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/why-do-we-quit-cold-turkey

> "Now tell me on the square – can I get by with this for the wedding – don't string me – tell me cold turkey."

Once you realise that "quitting cold turkey" is merely one popular use of "cold turkey," we can see that "starting a business cold turkey" or "hitting the school term cold turkey" or indeed "giving the facts cold turkey" are all very sensible and obvious.

Here's an analogy: consider the slang term "cool". One (of many) popular combos of "cool" is, say, "cool dude".  Say perhaps in 100 years on a list, someone was asking "With cool dude, what would you say for _ _ _ girl?"  Of course, the answer is "cool girl" - indeed cool had much broader use than that particular popular use.

Once again, particularly looking at the excellent MW early example, "cold turkey" is just another "cold" emphasis phrase, much like say "stone cold".  (Note that, indeed, you could certainly say "he quit heroin stone cold".) With that viewpoint, it's completely natural to say "we undertook the enterprise from a cold turkey start", exactly meaning we jumped in with no preparation, helpful pharmaceuticals, etc.

Fascinating question!

Comment: Love this @JoeBlow

Comment: I love you, @Drai!

Comment: @Drai, I wonder whether you forgot to upvote this? It's still at zero at the moment of writing.

Comment: @JoeBlow there are really two answers here. I don't want to accept "hot turkey" but I like your argument for just going with "cold turkey". Can u consider an edit?

Comment: @Mari-LouA in my experience on StackExchange it's quite common. As it is I don't want accept it.

Comment: @Drai then I shall withdraw my comment, and add no more.

Comment: I don't think "he quit heroin stone cold" sounds right.  To me, "stone cold" means unflappable; not fazed by anything.  And/or badass.  It's an adjective that applies to a person, not an adverb.  The only way you could quit heroin stone cold is the literal sense, i.e. by dying (body temperature = stone cold).  Upvoted for the rest of the answer, though.  @Drai: upvoting is separate from accepting.

Comment: HI Drai!  You know, I don't really believe in editing!  :)  I think it's informative as is, and "builds to" what I believe (and perhaps you believe) is the right answer - it's like a long-winded way to get to it.  I love long-winded paths.  Actually, i also like short paths, but, those are, um, different paths.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of expressions and idioms that people say when someone takes up a new hobby, for instance running, over-enthusiastically

1. [**go overboard**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/go-overboard)
   The obese man went completely overboard, and began running 10 miles a day

> to do something too much, or to be too ​excited or ​eager about something  e.g. *Ever wondered if your obsession with running has gone a little overboard, making you a runaholic?*

2. [**bite off more than you can chew**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bite-off-more-than-you-can-chew)
   The obese man bit off more than he could chew by running 10 miles a day

> to ​try to do something that is too ​difficult for you: e.g. *I ​think he's ​bitten off more than he can ​chew taking all those ​classes.*

3. [**full out**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/full-out)
   The obese man began running full out.

> As much or as far as possible; with maximum effort or power

4. [**throw yourself into something**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/throw-yourself-into-sth?topic=energetic-and-lively)
   The obese man threw himself into working out, and began running 10 miles a day

> to do something ​actively and ​enthusiastically:e.g. *She's ​thrown herself into this new ​job*

Answer (score 3):

You need a phrase that implies there is a drastic change in mood or behavior and it occurred rather suddenly.

> The obese man began running 10 miles a day ***just like that***.

or

> The man quit smoking just like that.

The phrase "just like that" is typically an adage to imply that something occurred suddenly or without warning. You might say something like:

> Then he hit him in the face just like that.

Or other times it is used as a chastisement of a request:

> You expect me to drop everything and help you, after everything you did, just like that!

These examples indicate that what is happening is not a long-term change, so are outside of your needs, but in similar scenarios you might say:

> He'll start a fight just like that.

or

> He expects people to help him just like that.

Also, when spoken, people often will snap their fingers while saying it, with the snap landing on "that". My impression of this usage lends the mind to another idiom with a close meaning:

> The obese man just snapped and began running 10 miles a day.

or

> In a snap, the man quit smoking.

And to follow the pattern of the other examples:

> He'll start a fight in a snap.
>
> He expect people to just snap and help him.

---

You could still use "cold turkey" in your example, but you need to change the subject and tone of the message.

> The obese man abandoned his sedentary lifestyle cold turkey.

It kind of works, but I'd rather use "just like that".

---

This is from an American English speaker. I've had very little exposure to other forms so it may not be understood where those are spoken.

Answer (score 2):

You could also try, "off the couch." This is typically employed in the context of athletics. One should note that is often (though not always) used in the case that one had done the activity regularly in the past, then quit, and is now starting abruptly, without a gradual reentry.

Comment: Your answer would be improved if you added a citation.  This term might be common knowledge in athletics, but it is new to me, and I am not a couch potato; I would appreciate a citation.

Answer (score 1):

The word is ***suddenly***.

It's okay to laugh.

Now that everyone has finally stopped laughing, let me explain:

It *may* come off as a bit archaic. But it's definitely the word here. Consider this brief passage from a Mark Twain story:

> The Southern heart is too impulsive; Southern hospitality is too lavish with the stranger. The paragraphs which I have written to-day, and into whose cold sentences your masterly hand has infused the fervent spirit of Tennesseean journalism, will wake up another nest of hornets. All that mob of editors will come--and they will come hungry, too, and want somebody for breakfast. I shall have to bid you adieu. I decline to be present at these festivities. I came South for my health, I will go back on the same errand, and ***suddenly***. Tennesseean journalism is too stirring for me."

Comment: Suddenly, a wild obese man appeared on the jogging lane! :P

Comment: @BiscuitBoy: ... cream puff in hand and looking content.

Comment: Thanks @Ricky, but not quite right. I'm really looking for a phrase more like an idiom than an adverb. Though I could sure go for a cream puff right now.

Comment: I think Twain was saying that he would likely have to leave on short notice without much choice in the matter...at the point of a pitchfork or under threat of lynching, perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

A possibility is "from a standing start"

> they built the world’s largest advertising agency from a standing start nineteen years ago

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/standing

This is probably not suitable for the specific example given though, since the sentence is already to do with running so it's likely to be taken literally.

Answer (score 1):

The obese man began running 10 miles a day, [like a boss].

The obese man began running 10 miles a day, [hardcore].

As I'm not much for idioms, maybe these?

The obese man [abruptly] began running 10 miles a day.

The obese man [painfully] began running 10 miles a day.

The obese man [diligently] began running 10 miles a day.

The obese man [honestly] began running 10 miles a day.

Answer (score 1):

The term you are looking for is "from scratch".

The obese man began running 10 miles a day from scratch.

from the very beginning, especially without utilizing or relying on any previous work for assistance.

Comment: I don't think this is quite what the question is going for

Answer (score 0):

Consider ***[take to something like a duck to water](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+to+like+a+duck+to+water)***

> (idiom) to learn how to do something very quickly and to enjoy doing it

[The Free Dictionary]

In your case, a slightly modified phrase would be -

> The obese man took to running ***like a duck to water***, clocking 10 miles a day.

This implies that the person started running and started enjoying it immensely from the word go.

Comment: Close, but I want to convey that the action is done despite other easier ways to do it. Duck to water makes me think it comes easy. Cold turkey is not easy.

Answer (score 0):

These might be closer to what you're asking (although they're not idioms)

> Against the advice of his doctor/trainer, the obese man began running 10 miles
>   a day.
>
> Against all reason and common sense, the obese man began running 10 miles a day (and suffered an immediate heart attack).
>
> Against all the laws of nature, the obese man began running 10 miles a day. He too, had been born on the planet of Krypton.

Answer (score 0):

**Hit the ground running.** This would be like *starting* something without 
easing into it, just like going cold-turkey is *quitting* something without easing out of it. 
That's as close as I was able to get.

> Jogging 10 miles a day, the Obese man hit the ground running.

Comment: This answer was already given by user155290

Answer (score 0):

I would use "go at [it] cold", as in "cold start".

As in, 'instead of warming up first, he went at it cold' if you want it in terms of exercise.

Or from the days before catalytic converters, you'd leave the car engine running a bit first, to warm it up, rather than turn it on and immediately drive away, with the engine still cold?

Answer (score 0):

The "dove into the deep end" answer is very good.

Another term for a sudden, vigorous start to something (thus, in a sense, the opposite of a *cold turkey* abrupt end) is a *jackrabbit start*.

The obese man made pulled a *jackrabbit start* in trying to get fit, going from nothing to running ten miles a day.

This is usually used fairly literally, and not as a metaphor. It is more applicable to starting an actual run at a fast running pace, than to starting a fitness program at a high load: *"When the gun went off, Joe made the mistake of a jackrabbit start, which he didn't recognize and correct. By the third lap, he was last in the pack, and didn't even come close to his best mile time.*"

Answer (score 0):

I've heard the saying "in it for a penny in it for a pound", which means going all the way in, and giving it 100%. I suppose if you mean stopping something altogether to 0%, you could use the saying I mentioned as an opposite to going cold turkey.

Answer (score -1):

Full throttle from the get-go. Pedal to the metal - use car-race analogies

Comment: Please explain your answer fully. Why do these suit the question?